# "Constructor FileReader in class filereader.FileReader cannot be applied to given types"

Tags: java, filereader

first time post here.

I am in the process of writing a Java program that takes an input text file, reads the contents, and then prints them to the screen and also creates an output file with the contents. I have set up the necessary writers, but when I try to use `BufferedReader readername = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));` it gives me the error in the title.

Any ideas what's causing it?

Here's the code.

```
public class FileReader 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
        File inFile = new File("inputText.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        String line = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Contents.txt"));

        while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        writer.write(line);
                        System.out.println("File 'Contents.txt' successfully written");
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fully qualified class name `java.io.FileReader` since you have a class already called `FileReader` when calling a `BufferedReader`, like so:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(inFile));
```

Without fully qualifying your `FileReader` (or specifying imports), the compiler will use your declared `FileReader`.

Comment: @Ian Johnson, Glad to have been of help. Don't forget to accept the answer that has helped by clicking on the tick under the answer score.

Comment: Another problem, when I try to close the reader and writer under the catch, it says it cannot find the symbol even though I've declared it further up.

Comment: You must declare the `reader` **outside** the `try` block. Next time, post another question if it's unrelated to the current question or update the question. We cannot solve your problems through comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your class name is `FileReader` and you want to use `java.io.FileReader` hence compiler is confused and instead of `java.io.FileReader` it assumes it be your class. Basically your ClassName shadows the name from java.io package.

Rename your class to something else like `MyFileReader` or use fully qualified named `java.io.FileReader`